# How to make a textbox readonly/editable in angular 2 based on some condition

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a textbox, I want to make in readonly at some conditions and editable field in few conditions, So the field should toggle between read only/editable based on the condition , How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the following (Angular 4):

```
<input [readonly]="isReadOnly">
```

If you use attr.readonly then the input will always be read-only because the readonly attribute will be present even if its value is false. By using [readonly] Angular will only place the attribute if isReadOnly is true.

After, you assign the value as you wish:

```
// when you want to be read-only
isReadOnly = true;
// whe you want to be editable
isReadOnly = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `[readonly]="varInYourComponent"` in your input field, on template.
And in your component declare and you should work with this variable:

```
boolean varInYourComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

use property binding to achieve that

```
[property]="flag"
```